# Conditional Type Checking based on function parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

Im writing a custom Hook that can take either one or two strings, or an object with more granular parameters. I wanted to add a conditional type check to check for a type of that param and do some logic based on it. Here are the relevant snippets:

```js
// The hook itself
const [error, loading, data] = useFirestore('posts', 'test'); // in a string version
const [error, loading, data] = useFirestore({...someProps}); // in a object version version
```

```
// The types that i defined for them
type queryType<T> = T extends string ? string : documentQueryType;
type docType<T> = T extends string ? string : never;

type documentQueryType = {
    collection: string;
    query: string[] | string[][];
    limit: number;
    orderBy: string; // todo limit this to be only special words
    order: string; // todo same as above
    startAt: number;
    endAt: number;
};
```

```
// The function that is in the question
export const useFirestore = <T>(query: queryType<T>, doc?: docType<T>) => {...rest of the function
```

How would I make the last snippet work so when passed an object it sets `doc` to never, and when passed a string sets the `doc` to string?

Answer (score 0):

This can be partially achieved with conditional types, but it may not be 100% type-safe. Since `doc` is optional, it will not be required when the `query` is a `string`, and will still allow `undefined` when `query` is an object.

However, if these two scenarios are not an issue, this can be achieved with conditional types:

```js
// Simplified type
type DocumentQueryType = {
  collection: string;
};

// The two types of queries that are accepted
type QueryTypes = string | DocumentQueryType;

// Given the query type, infer the doc type
type InferDocType<QueryType> = QueryType extends string ? string : never;

const useFirestore = <QueryType extends QueryTypes>(query: QueryType, doc?: InferDocType<QueryType>) => { }

// Valid Examples
useFirestore('posts', 'test');
useFirestore({ collection: "" });

// Valid Examples (may not want these?)
useFirestore('posts');
useFirestore({ collection: "" }, undefined);

// Invalid Examples
useFirestore({ collection: "" }, "test");
// Argument of type '"test"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.(2345)
useFirestore('posts', null);
// Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | undefined'.(2345)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I was stuck too much in my previous approach to even think about this. Very clear explanation and worked straight away!